# How to run PHP and Tomcat on same server environment?

Tags: java, php, wordpress, apache, tomcat

Asked this on AskUbuntu a while ago:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/630897/apache-httpd-backed-by-both-tomcat-and-php
but no answers there so I decided to ask here.

Once again - let's say I have server accessible by some domain name e.g. http://mywebapp.com/

I would like to setup the following on that server:

- all requests like `http://mywebapp.com/blog*` are handled by `PHP` server (Wordpress blog engine to be specific)
- all **other** requests `http://mywebapp.com/*` are handled by `Apache Tomcat`

I thought that this could be achievable by putting `Apache HTTPD` server in front of both `Tomcat` and `PHP` servers but couldn't find configurations to achieve this.

Could someone please provide any hint on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with mod_jk:

1) Enable module "mod_jk" in your Apache web servers httpd.conf. Uncomment this line, by removing the leading hash:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
```

If you are on Linux type:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-jk
sudo a2enmod jk
```

2) Edit [TOMCAT_DIR]/conf/server.xml. Add a "jvmRoute" attribute to the "engine" element:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat">
```

Uncomment the AJP connector (the http connector may be disabled):

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

3) Create a file "workers.properties", next to "httpd.conf". Add this content and set right ip/port:

```
worker.list=tomcat

worker.tomcat.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat.host=127.0.0.1
#This is the port from the AJP connector, not HTTP!
worker.tomcat.port=8009
worker.tomcat.lbfactor=10
```

4) Add this mapping at the end of httpd.conf and replace [PATH_TO_DIR] by the absolute path:

```
<IfModule jk_module>

  JkWorkersFile [PATH_TO_DIR]\workers.properties
  JkLogFile [PATH_TO_DIR]\mod_jk.log 
  JkLogLevel INFO 
  JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories 

  SetEnvIf Request_URI "/error/*" no-jk
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "/blog*"   no-jk

  JkMount    /                    tomcat
  JkMount    /*                   tomcat

</IfModule>
```

5) Start Tomcat and restart Httpd.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I am trying to follow your instructions, can you please check this question : http://serverfault.com/questions/740534/apache-webserver-tomcat-runing-multiple-tomcat-webapps-and-apache-webserver/740569?noredirect=1#comment926117_740569