# Redirecting to multiple webapps in same Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I must say that I tried a lot of possibilities but my knowledgment in Apache WS is not too much advanced.

```
Apache Web Server version: 2.2.22
OS: Centos 6 64 bits
Tomcat version: 7.0.57
```

What I need to achieve is the following:
I have some plain websites defined this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example1@example1.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/sites/example1/"
        ServerName example1.com
        ErrorLog logs/example1-error_log
        CustomLog logs/example1-access_log common
        RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://www.example1.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example1@example1.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/sites/example1/"
        ServerName www.example1.com
        ErrorLog logs/example1-error_log
        CustomLog logs/example1-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I have a tomcat with several webapps, each one accessible by its own context.
I must access each one of this webapps from a different domain. For example, I have the following webapps: wbExample1, wbExample2, wbExample3

It should be accessible this way:

```
www.example1.com/wbExample1
www.example2.com/wbExample2
www.example3.com/wbExample3
```

So, the domain defined for each website must also access to an specific webapp.

For an extra, I would like to know if **www.example1.com/wbExample1** could be accessible with url **www.example1.com/contact** without showing the name context of the webapp and showing the text **contact or contact.html**.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. First you need to set up a redirecton from Apache WebServer to Apache Tomcat. How to sdo that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935328/how-to-run-php-and-tomcat-on-same-server-environment/30938420#30938420). Just remove the "/blog* no-jk" line.

The second thing you need to do is, creating virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

will listen to all domains, you can leave it this way, in this scenario. Edit [Tomcat]/conf/server.xml and add virtual hosts for every domain, having *different names and appBases*:

```
<Host name="example1.com" appBase="webapps-example1" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
 ...
</Host>
```

Create directories next to the default "webapps" directoy: "webapps-example1", ... Be sure Tomcat can access them.

Restart Tomcat and deploy your applications as the **root context** of your vhosts, i.e.: [Tomcat]/webapps-example1/ROOT. You can do that by renaming them to ROOT.war before deployment. That way you can access your applications without the additional application name.

Comment: I've just tried what you answered but it didn't work. The result is the error 

'jk_translate::mod_jk.c (3488): missing uri map for www.example1.com:/Servlet/index
jk_map_to_storage::mod_jk.c (3647): missing uri map for www.example1.com:/Servlet/index'

Comment: Did you define the mappings (JKMount ...) inside the <virtualHost></virtualHost> definition? http://serverfault.com/questions/309563/how-get-i-the-tomcat-ajp-connectors-working

Answer (score 0):

I tried using mod proxy instead of mod jk.

I've just defined my VirtualHost like this (last four lines are new):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example1@example1.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/sites/example1/"
        ServerName www.example1.com
        ErrorLog logs/example1-error_log
        CustomLog logs/example1-access_log common
       ProxyRequests off
       ProxyPreserveHost on
       ProxyPass /contact.html http://localhost:8081/Servlet/lmdd
       ProxyPassReverse /contact.html http://localhost:8081/Servlet/lmdd
</VirtualHost>
```

With this setup it worked like I expected, I can access to the index page of my webapp, except in the case that when I try to submit the page, it returns

**The requested URL /Servlet/sendFormLMDD was not found on this server.**

In Tomcat logs there's no logs because is never been reached.

In Apache WS logs:

access log - "POST /Servlet/sendFormLMDD HTTP/1.1" 404 192

error log - File does not exist: /opt/sites/example1/Servlet, referer: http://example1.com/contact.html

The reason why fails is quite clear, it is trying to find the servlet in the path where the plain website is located, not in tomcat. What can I do to tell Apache to go to tomcat in POST requests?

For more information, this is the form definition:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sendFormLMDD" method="post" id="updateForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

where ${pageContext.request.contextPath} is resolving to Servlet.

Thanks for your help!